# Definition of recurrent stochastic process, in general

Tags: stochastic-processes, recurrent-events, kolmogorov-axioms

This interesting question:
[Recurrence definition for a Markov chain](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48602/recurrence-definition-for-a-markov-chain)
gives the definition of a **recurrent** state for some discrete process.

I was wondering, in the case of a **continuous** (time) process, what is the correct way to define a state $y$ as recurrent? In that case, would the (first) sum become an integral? I imagine that I might consider the probability of a "continuous" union of events, but how would I actually represent that?

What about the very general case where we consider a stochastic process of any nature (discrete and continuous, mixed, etc.)?

Is there a general name for the class of processes where all the (interesting) states considered are recurrent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of recurrence is important in stochastic processes, and it changes depending on the nature of the process, particularly when comparing discrete-time processes like Markov chains to continuous-time processes.

**Discrete-Time Processes (e.g., Discrete Markov Chains)**

In discrete-time stochastic processes, particularly in the context of discrete Markov chains, a state is defined as recurrent if there is a certainty of returning to that state after a finite number of steps. More formally:

**Recurrent State**: A state $y$ in a discrete Markov chain is recurrent if, starting from $y$, the probability of returning to $y$ eventually is 1. In mathematical terms, if we denote $P_{yy}^{(n)}$ as the probability of returning to state $y$ in $n$ steps, then $y$ is recurrent if the sum of these probabilities over all $n$ is infinite:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P_{yy}^{(n)} = \infty $$

This definition implies that a recurrent state will be visited infinitely often over the long run. In discrete Markov chains, this is a key property that determines the long-term behaviour of the chain.

**Continuous-Time Processes:**

The notion of a recurrent state is adapted to the continuous character of time for continuous-time stochastic processes, such as those described by continuous-time Markov chains (CTMCs):

**Recurrent State**: A state $y$ in a continuous-time stochastic process is recurrent if, given that the process is in state $y$ at time $t$, the probability that it will return to $y$ at some time $t' > t$ is 1. This can be expressed using an integral over the transition probability function.
If we denote $p_{yy}(t, t')$ as the transition probability from state $y$ at time $t$ to the same state $y$ at a later time $t'$, then $y$ is recurrent if:

$$
\int_{t}^{\infty} p_{yy}(t, t') \, dt' = 1
$$

**Stochastic Processes in General**

The idea of recurrence remains similar for stochastic processes in general, which may include discrete, continuous, or mixed types, but must be modified to the details of each process. The repeated return to a specific condition is always the key:

The definition of recurrence in mixed processes (which include both discrete and continuous components) would likely include a combination of summation and integration while respecting the nature of each component.

**Classes of Processes with Recurrent States**

- Ergodic Processes: The term "ergodic" refers to a type of stochastic process in which all states are recurrent. Not only are all states recurrent in an ergodic process, but the process also satisfies additional features such as aperiodicity and positive recurrence, ensuring that long-term statistical properties can be established.
- Positive recurrence is a more powerful concept than recurrence in that a recurrent state is visited not only infinitely frequently but also with a finite expected return time.

**Applications:**

- The notion of recurrence in stochastic processes is widely used in many domains, including physics (e.g., particle systems), finance (e.g., stock price modelling), biology (e.g., population dynamics), and others. The nature of the process (discrete, continuous, or mixed) affects how recurrence is defined and analysed in each application.

To sum up, while the fundamental concept of recurrence is the same across different types of stochastic processes, its specific definition and the mathematical tools used to analyse it (such as summation in discrete-time and integration in continuous-time) differ depending on whether the process is discrete, continuous, or mixed. Ergodic processes are a type of process in which recurrence is a distinguishing property.

Comment: Thank you very much, Robert. I am sorry I am still not allowed to upvote :-) In case we wanted to avoid talking about transition probability functions (which I don't see much outside of Markov processes), can we still use an argument like the one used in the previously referenced answer, possibly using some integral or uncountable union of events?

Comment: @Jada I have just upvoted your question, so you can now upvote people's contributions :)  As to your question, Yes, you can define recurrence in general stochastic processes without explicitly referring to transition probability functions, which are indeed more specific to Markov processes. Instead, you can frame the concept in terms of the likelihood of revisiting a state or set within the state space over time. This approach is more general and can be applied to a broader range of stochastic processes.